# Using AND/OR mysql commands with FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql

Trying to select a query in php/mysql to get "Upcoming Items" in a calendar. We store the dates in the DB as a unix time. Here's what my query looks like right now

```
SELECT *
FROM `calendar`
WHERE (`eventDate` > '$yesterday') 
OR (FROM_UNIXTIME(eventDate, '%m') > '$current_month' AND `$yearly` = '1')
ORDER BY `eventDate`
LIMIT 4
```

This is giving me an error "Unknown column '' in 'where clause'". I'm sure it has to do with my use of parenthesis (which I've never used before in a query) and the FROM_UNIXTIME command.

Can someone help me out and let me know how I've screwed this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This to me looks suspicious:

```
`$yearly`
```

What is the value of $yearly? Is it empty? When you use backticks MySQL treats the contents as the name of a column.

Perhaps you meant to create a string instead, in which case you should use a different type of quote:

```
'$yearly' = '1'
```

Or perhaps you intended to refer to the column `yearly`:

```
yearly = '1'
```

Another tip is to print the SQL query *after* the PHP variables have been interpolated as this sometimes makes it easier to understand the error message from MySQL. I'd imagine your query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `calendar`
WHERE (`eventDate` > '1295071200') 
OR (FROM_UNIXTIME(eventDate, '%m') > '1' AND `` = '1')
ORDER BY `eventDate`
LIMIT 4
```

The suspicious part is here:

```
`` = '1'
```

Comment: Oh man, I think it's time for me to go to bed. Of course that was the problem that I completely overlooked. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a column named $yearly ?, try removing the dollar sign